# JQuery - Ajax failing to call and excute php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Would you guys be able to help me figure out where my ajax call is failing? It does actually call the correct php script but it fails to delete a user as per their id. I have placed my code below.

**cms/users HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index">Project name</a>
                            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="../cms/events">Manage Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manage Speakers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manage Surveys</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manage Contact Lists</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../users">Manage Users</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hassan Said <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                            <li><a href="../manage/1">Manage Account</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="../users">Manage Users</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="../logout">Logout</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">CMS Users</h2>
    <span class="alert alert-success form-control" id="delete_succuessful"></span> 
    <span class="alert alert-danger form-control" id="delete_unsuccessful"></span>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>View</th>
                            <th>User Active?</th>
                    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>imaqsood</td><td>Maqsood</td><td>Irum</td>    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirm" data-first_name="Irum" data-last_name=" Maqsood "  data-user_id=" 2 " class="confirmDelete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
                                  <td><a href="../cms/edituser/2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>

                            <td><a href="../cms/viewuser/2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></td>

                                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
                            </tr><tr><td>hsaid</td><td>Said</td><td>Hassan</td>   <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirm" data-first_name="Hassan" data-last_name=" Said "  data-user_id=" 2 " class="confirmDelete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
                                  <td><a href="../cms/edituser/1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>

                            <td><a href="../cms/viewuser/1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></td>

                                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
                            </tr><tr><td>t</td><td>T</td><td>T</td>   <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirm" data-first_name="t" data-last_name=" t "  data-user_id=" 2 " class="confirmDelete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
                                  <td><a href="../cms/edituser/18"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>

                            <td><a href="../cms/viewuser/18"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></td>

                                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
                            </tr>       </tbody>
    </table>

            <a href="../cms/edituser"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add A New User</button></a>
    </div>


<div class="modal fade" id="deleteConfirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="hidden" id="currDeleteId">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete: <em><span class="last_name" id="last_name"></span>, <span class="first_name" id="first_name"></span></em></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete-confirmation">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal --></div>
```

**cms/users JQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".confirmDelete", function () {
    var userDeleteFirstName = $(this).data('first_name');
    var userDeleteLastName = $(this).data('last_name');
    var userDeleteUserId = $(this).data('user_id');
    $(".first_name").text( userDeleteFirstName );
    $(".last_name").text( userDeleteLastName.trim() );
    $("#currDeleteId").val( userDeleteUserId.trim() );
});

$(document).on("click", "#delete-confirmation", function(){
    var id_to_delete = $('#currDeleteId').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../cms/delete/" + id_to_delete,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(){
            $("#delete_succuessful").text("User " + userDeleteLastName + ", " + userDeleteFirstName + " was deleted.");
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#delete_unsuccuessful").text("User " + userDeleteLastName + ", " + userDeleteFirstName + " was not deleted.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**/cmscontroller/delete PHP Script**

```
public function deleteUser($id){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['cms_user_session'])){
            header('location:.login');
        }else{
            echo $id;
            $query = $this->Cms->where('cms_user_id','=',$_SESSION['cms_user_session']);
            $query = $this->Cms->find();

            $first_name = ucwords($query[0]['first_name']);
            $last_name = ucwords($query[0]['last_name']);

            $this->set('title', strtoupper('cms').ucwords(' deleting user'));

            $query = $this->Cms->delete(array('cms_user_id',$id));

        }
    }
```

I think the problem may be with the ajax call because it does send the data to /cms/delete/id as confirmed by the inspect element of firefox. However the ajax success call does nothing. Please let me know any ideas

Comment: Have you checked your PHP error log?

Comment: Did you check the status code of the response in the firebug network tab? What happens if you put this URL /cms/delete/id (being id a valid *cms_user_id*) in the browser directly (while logged in of course)?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no errors in the php script (I have error reporting enabled and no errors show).

Comment: @mTorres I get a 200 ok code from the inspector. With a request url of localhost/framework/cms/delete/2 and method of post

Comment: @NSaid Does the function `deleteUser` at `php` actually get called ? Where does the e.g., `2` sent to php at end of `url` get processed by php ? Does `id_to_delete` become `$id` ? Tried sending `id_to_delete` as `data: {"id":id_to_delete}` at `$.ajax()` ? and listen at php with `$_POST["id"]` ?

Comment: try getting rid of echo $id; and, and the end of the routine, echo true if the delete completed or false if it did not.

Comment: @guest271314 checking that out now

Comment: for anyone looking at the code and trying to figure it out, the delete function called $this->Cms->delete() which was throwing a PDO exception